# JSF primefaces datatable lazy loading multiple selection

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i was developing lazy loading dataTable with primeface with pagination.

SelectionMode is multiple.

I was selected 3 check box in first page, now i am go to page 2 and select another 3 check box, now return to page 1. this time check box selection not present in page 1.

i need to page 1 and 2 selection data. how to get.

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547359/pdatatable-selections-are-lost-after-paginating-a-lazydatamodel/24360708#24360708