# p:dataTable selections are lost after paginating a LazyDataModel

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, pagination, lazy-loading

My problem is that after I've selected a few items on the 1st page, if I paginate to another page and come back, my initial selections are not shown. I've tried to implement the `SelectableDataModel` as well as using the `rowKey` attribute but the problem persists.

This is my test bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MrBean {
    private List<Item> chosenItems;
    private LazyDataModel lazyModel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void prepareTest() {
        this.lazyModel = new LazyItemDataModel();
    }

    public void countItems() {
        System.out.println("TEST 3: chosenItems's size: " + chosenItems.size());
    }

    private class LazyItemDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Item> implements SelectableDataModel<Item> {
        @Override
        public Item getRowData(String rowKey) {
            System.out.println("TEST 1: getRowData");
            Iterator<Item> iter = ((List<Item>) this.getWrappedData()).iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Item item = iter.next();
                if (item.getId().equals(rowKey)) {
                    return item;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getRowKey(Item item) {
            return item.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Item> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters) {
            System.out.println("TEST 2: load");
            // Code to retrieve items from database
        }
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

This is my test page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable id="itemTable" var="item" value="#{mrBean.items}" rows="5" 
                         paginator="true" selection="#{mrBean.chosenItems}" lazy="true" >

                <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="mrBean.countItems" />                    

                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />

                <p:column headerText="ID">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" /> 
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" /> 
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I'd be very grateful if you could show me what I've done wrong here.

**UPDATE:** After I added more `System.out.println("TEST")` to the above code, I observed the following things:

1. On the console, every time I paginate, `TEST 1: getRowData` is always printed before `TEST 2: load`. As a consequence, I believe the method `#LazyDataModel.getWrappedData()` may return data from the old page. At first, I thought this method's goal was to retrieve the selected rows to highlight on the table. However, if this method is called before `load`, there's no way it can do the job right?
2. After I selected the 1st 2 items on the 1st page, on the console, I saw `TEST 3: chosenItems's size: 2`. If I paginate to the 2nd page and then back to the 1st page, the selections are lost as mentioned. However, if I continued to select another item, on the console, I saw `TEST 3: chosenItems's size: 3`. Obviously, the `chosenItems` list still kept my old selections but they're not rendered on the table.

Comment: +1 for providing a simple and testable SSCCE ;-) Next time consider adding an `Item` subclass to make it copy'paste'run

Comment: I'm not sure about the concrete problem. Your bean is view scoped, surely it should be recreated with all its properties set to default when you revisit the page? If you would like to interact with the same view, then you should consider rendering the results conditionally in the same view instead of moving to another view.

Comment: @BalusC I think that when he talks about moving to other page he's actually meaning table pages (paginator) instead of views.

Comment: @Xtreme: ohw right, yes now the question makes completely sense. I took the liberty to edit the title and the word "move" anyway to make it much more clearer.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes can you provide a better explanation of what are you doing? Replace your "// Code to retrieve items from database" by a hard-coded list filling. Don't know why but I am unable to get the table filled at client side, even the model seems to be well-formed while view rendering. Could you write a copy'paste'go code?

Comment: @XtremeBiker: I will add some code tomorrow morning :). For the time being, perhaps you can view my updates :D.

Comment: It would be good if you try to [follow this convention](http://sscce.org/) as much as possible. Better if you can remove the dependencies to your DAO.

Comment: Mr.J4mes, the @Ceyda's answer works for me. I've done one example with jpa [here](https://github.com/gilbertoca/jsf-sandbox/tree/fix-datatable-Issue-1407-jpa).

Answer (score 4):

This is because when `SelectionFeature` is decoded a new list is created.

And if `table.getRowData(rowKeys[i])` (related to your `LazyDataModel` implementation) returns null your old selectıons in the previous page are gone.may try to solve it by changing your LazyDataModel implementation I didn't try these but take a look at [**this**](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23988) and [**this**](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10388)

Had the same problem and I think this solution is easier if you have a lot of different tables implementing LazyDataModel.

This is what I did: check if it is lazy first then add currently selected rows to the selectionList.

For primefaces 4.0

**1)Override DataTableRenderer**

In faces-config.xml

```
<render-kit>
   <renderer>
       <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
       <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.DataTableRenderer</renderer-type>
       <renderer-class>com.package.LazyDataTableRenderer</renderer-class>
   </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

And

```
public class LazyDataTableRenderer extends DataTableRenderer {
static Map<DataTableFeatureKey,DataTableFeature> FEATURES;

    static {
        FEATURES = new HashMap<DataTableFeatureKey,DataTableFeature>();
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.DRAGGABLE_COLUMNS, new DraggableColumnsFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.FILTER, new FilterFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.PAGE, new PageFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.SORT, new SortFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.RESIZABLE_COLUMNS, new ResizableColumnsFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.SELECT, new LazySelectionFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.ROW_EDIT, new RowEditFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.CELL_EDIT, new CellEditFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.ROW_EXPAND, new RowExpandFeature());
        FEATURES.put(DataTableFeatureKey.SCROLL, new ScrollFeature());
    }

    @Override
    public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        DataTable table = (DataTable) component;

        for(Iterator<DataTableFeature> it = FEATURES.values().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            DataTableFeature feature = it.next();

            if(feature.shouldDecode(context, table)) {
                feature.decode(context, table);
            }
        }

        decodeBehaviors(context, component);        
    }
}
```

**2)Override SelectionFeature's decode**

**Updated**: edited to allow deselecting

```
public class LazySelectionFeature extends org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature{

    @Override
    public void decode(FacesContext context, DataTable table) {
        String clientId = table.getClientId(context);
        Map<String,String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        String selection = params.get(clientId + "_selection");

        if(table.isSingleSelectionMode())
            decodeSingleSelection(table, selection);
        else
            decodeMultipleSelection(context, table, selection);
    }

    void decodeSingleSelection(DataTable table, String selection) {
            if(ComponentUtils.isValueBlank(selection))
                table.setSelection(null);
            else
                table.setSelection(table.getRowData(selection));
        }

    void decodeMultipleSelection(FacesContext context, DataTable table, String selection) {
        Class<?> clazz = table.getValueExpression("selection").getType(context.getELContext());
        boolean isArray = clazz.isArray();

        if(!isArray && !List.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            throw new FacesException("Multiple selection reference must be an Array or a List for datatable " + table.getClientId());
        }

        if(ComponentUtils.isValueBlank(selection)) {
            if(isArray) {
                table.setSelection(Array.newInstance(clazz.getComponentType(), 0));
            }
            else {
                table.setSelection(new ArrayList<Object>());
            }
        }
        else {
            String[] rowKeys = selection.split(",");
            List<Object> selectionList = new ArrayList<Object>();

            boolean lazy=table.isLazy();
            if (lazy) {

            List<String> currentRowKeys = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(rowKeys));
            if (table.getSelection() != null) {
                List<Object> alreadySelected = (List<Object>) table.getSelection();

                for (Object object : alreadySelected) {//For deselecting
                    Object rowKeyFromModel = table.getRowKeyFromModel(object);
                    if (currentRowKeys.contains(rowKeyFromModel)) {
                        selectionList.add(object);
                        currentRowKeys.remove(rowKeyFromModel);
                    } 
                }                    
            }
            for (String key : currentRowKeys) {//For selecting  
                Object rowData = table.getRowData(key);
                if (rowData != null && !selectionList.contains(rowData)) {
                       selectionList.add(rowData);
                }
            }

        }else{

                for(int i = 0; i < rowKeys.length; i++) {
                    Object rowData = table.getRowData(rowKeys[i]);

                    if(rowData != null)
                        selectionList.add(rowData);
                }

            }

            if(isArray) {
                Object selectionArray = Array.newInstance(clazz.getComponentType(), selectionList.size());
                table.setSelection(selectionList.toArray((Object[]) selectionArray));
            }
            else {
                table.setSelection(selectionList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Might not be the best solution but should work, let me know if there is a better way. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Ceyda's solution works - it preserves to selection after pagination. But has one problem, after selection you won't be able to unselect it - why?

Comment: I think it is necessary a correction in datatable.js file as well.

Comment: @Gilbertoca I think changing `if(rowData != null && !selectionList.contains(rowData))selectionList.add(rowData);` at the end of _for_ in the _if(lazy)_ portion to `if(rowData != null){
 if(!selectionList.contains(rowData)){selectionList.add(rowData);}
 else{selectionList.remove(rowData);}
}` should work if I remember correctly. It's been a while so I no longer have the code or a test environment so let me know if it works and I will update the answer.

Comment: would you mind to check out [this code](https://github.com/gilbertoca/jsf-sandbox/tree/fix-datatable-Issue-1407)?

Comment: @Gilbertoca I ran the code, it seems that I remembered incorrectly and what I said in the previous comment was total nonsense,sorry. Fixed the if(lazy) part, edited the answer. Deselecting now should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, @Ceyda! It works perfectly. I've done one example with jpa [here](https://github.com/gilbertoca/jsf-sandbox/tree/fix-datatable-Issue-1407-jpa).

Comment: I've found a problem, if you use a rowKey other than String it doesn't work. A datatable bug or feature?

Answer (score 4):

In webPage just add a event for when page switch:

```
<p:ajax event="page" listener="#{listingBean.updateSelected()}" />
```

In the listingBean, just save the selected:

```
private List<Entity> selectedInstances;
private List<Entity> selectedInstancesSaved;

public List<Entity> getSelectedInstances()
{
    return selectedInstancesSaved;
}

public void setSelectedInstances(List<Entity> selectedInstances)
{
    this.selectedInstances = selectedInstances;
}

public void updateSelected()
{
    if (selectedInstances != null && !selectedInstances.isEmpty()) {
        for (Entity inst : lazyModel.getDatasource()) {
            if (selectedInstances.contains(inst)) {
                selectedInstancesSaved.add( inst);
            } else {
                selectedInstancesSaved.remove( inst);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, simple and straightforward :)

Answer (score 3):

Just implement the property bound to selection property of DataTable (`selection="#{pageBackingForm.selectedEntityList}"`) like this and it will work :

```
    private Map<Integer, List<Entity>> selectedEntityListMap = new Hashtable<>();

    public List<Entity> getSelectedEntityList() {
        return selectedEntityListMap.get(getCurrentEntitySelectionPage());
    }

    public void setSelectedEntityList(List<Entity> selectedEntityList) {
        if (selectedEntityList == null) {
            selectedEntityListMap.remove(getCurrentEntitySelectionPage());
            return;
        }

        selectedEntityListMap.put(getCurrentEntitySelectionPage(), selectedEntityList);
    }

    public Integer getCurrentEntitySelectionPage() {
        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("formId:dataTableId");
        return dataTable.getPage();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

While Bruno's solution works for keeping selections across paginations, it doesn't account for retaining selections on an individual page (i.e. when never changing pages).

This problem can be resolved more simply by using the *rowSelectCheckbox* and *rowUnselectCheckbox* ajax events, in addition to having a separate "saved" row list.

**JSF:**

```
 <p:dataTable selection="#{myBean.selectedRows}" ... >
   <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" process="@this" listener="#{myBean.onSelectRow}" />
   <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" process="@this" listener="#{myBean.onUnselectRow}" />
   <p:column selectionMode="multiple" ... />
    ...
 </p:dataTable>
```

**Backing Bean:**

```
    private List<MyRowClass> selectedRows;
    private List<MyRowClass> selectedRowsSaved;

    ...

    public void onSelectRow(SelectEvent event){
        MyRowClass row = (MyRowClass) event.getObject();
        selectedRowsSaved.add(row);
    }

    public void onUnselectRow(UnselectEvent event){
        MyRowClass row = (MyRowClass) event.getObject();
        selectedRowsSaved.remove(row);
    }

    public List<MyRowClass> getSelectedRows(){
        return selectedRowsSaved;
    }

    public void setSelectedRows(List<MyRowClass> selectedRows){
        this.selectedRows = selectedRows;
    }
```

This way the list of saved rows is always kept up to date without needing a "page" ajax event.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with my data table. Although my case is a bit different because I am using **selectBooleanCheckbox** instead. I found a simple solution that works for me. It hit me when you said "old selection are not rendered in the table".

- strap the checkbox with a **a4j:support event**

code:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{batch.toPortfolio}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```