# primefaces LazyDataModel executed getRowData(String rowKey) before load()

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, lazydatamodel

My problem is the same this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547359/pdatatable-selections-are-lost-after-paginating-a-lazydatamodel), and I found that primefaces's LazyDataModel executed getRowData(String rowKey) before load(params). Is there any problem if getRowData execute after load?

Comment: I fail to see why you ask this question.

Comment: I selected some items on one page, if i paginate to another page and come back, my initial selections are not shown. But if i call a back bean method with process the datatable, it will get the selections. Or if i use  component update the datatable, the selections will shown. So i found the question. And i know if i retrieve item from database in getRowData, my selections will shown. So i think why getRowData is called before load, if load is called first, the getRowData could retrieve item by LazyDataModel.getWrappedData() instead of database. @Kukeltje